# Simple Jquery CheckAll /UncheckAll checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#masterChecks input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
   var togClass=$(this).attr('class');
   if($(this).attr('checked')){

    //need to make sure all checkboxes for this class is checked, when the
    //master checkbox is checked.
    $('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "inline-block");
}
else
{
        //need to make sure all checkboxes for this class is unchecked, when the
    //master checkbox is checked.
    $('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "none");

}
});
```

});

I have Html with many divs, and many classes.  There are many checkboxs.  Now i am checking the mastercheckbox, which will hide the css of all attributes that have the same class as the checkbox.  I also have a set of local checkboxes which do the same but only for the div they are in.  I want the Jquery uncheck the local checbox with the same class when it is unchecked, and vice versa.  here is the html struccture

```
<div id="masterChecks">
   // checbox here with class="sampleclass"
</div>
 <div class="sampleclass">
      //local checkbox here 
 </div>
```

it seems very straight forward , but cant get it to work,

ive tried some things like this:

```
 $('div.' + togClass + 'input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','checked');
```

can anyone help?

Comment: They changed it to attr('checked', true );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the jquery function [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check the status of the checkbox and then use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to cicle and set the status of all the checkbox with the same class to the one of the master:

```
$('#masterChecks input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
 var checkclass= $(this).attr('class');
if($(this).is(':checked'))
   $('div.' + checkclass + ' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
       $(this).attr('checked', true);
   });
 else   
    $('div.' + checkclass + ' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
   });
});
```

edit:
   added jsfiddle of working code: http://jsfiddle.net/CFeam/2/

Comment: cleaned the bad class variables, and put a jsfiddle so you can see it working :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Where you can iterate all your checkboxes and see if they are checked

Answer (score 0):

Try it by:

```
$('#masterChecks input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
var yourClass = $(this).attr('class');
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
    $('div.' + yourClass + ' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });
}
else
{
    $('div.' + yourClass + ' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
}
});​
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kTBr/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your document ready function :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#masterChecks input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
       var togClass=$(this).attr('class');
       $(togClass).click(function(){
             if($('#masterChecks').is(':checked'){
                $('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "inline-block");
                $(togClass).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('checked','checked');      
                });  
             }else{
                $('div.' + togClass ).css("display", "none");
                $(togClass).each(function(){
                    $(this).removeAttr('checked');      
                });  
             }
            });
        });        
    });
```